# Disk Space Changes with Command Used

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Can anyone help me understand why I get different disk space results for /mnt/kvm_images depending on the command used? This is in Ubuntu 14.04.

du gives this result:

```
andrew@ubuntu:~$ sudo du -sh /mnt/kvm_images/ 
  20K     /mnt/kvm_images/
```

df this result:

```
andrew@ubuntu:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root         90G  9.1G   76G  11% /
none                               4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                               963M  4.0K  963M   1% /dev
tmpfs                              195M  660K  195M   1% /run
none                               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                               974M     0  974M   0% /run/shm
none                               100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                          236M   38M  186M  17% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-kvm_images  394G   71M  374G   1% /mnt/kvm_images
```

And last ls:

```
andrew@ubuntu:~$ ls -lh /mnt/kvm_images/
total 16K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   50G Mar 26 04:00 desktop.img
drwx------ 2 root         root  16K Mar 22 15:17 lost+found
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root         root 200G Mar 25 00:33 monitoring.img
```

Comment: Those `.img` files are sparse files.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks. Your comment help me find this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sparse_file) which explained it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan D. is right. Because they are sparse files, different commands treat their size differently. Some report the actual size on disk, others the amount of space the file system has allocated for it. Apparent-size option for du allows one to toggle between both.

```
andrew@ubuntu:~$ sudo du -sh --apparent-size /mnt/kvm_images/
51G     /mnt/kvm_images/
andrew@ubuntu:~$ sudo du -sh /mnt/kvm_images/
6.2G    /mnt/kvm_images/
```